# 404 error after deploying web app to AWS Elastic beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am receiving a 404 error after deploying my AWS Application to Elastic beanstalk

**NOTE THE PROJECT RUNS FINE LOCALLY**

I think the issue is, it is unable to find my html files (thats why it is throwing a 404).

These are the steps I have taken

1. I have built an .JAR artifact using Intellij(I think there is a mistake in this process).
2. I then selected Tomcat as my environment running Amazon Corretto 11.
3. I then uploaded my said .JAR file

**This is how I built my .JAR**

I clicked on project structure in Intellij. Which opens this window. [Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRjga.png)

**I then clicked on the plus sign and selected JAR from modules with dependencies**. This is what opens up and this is my selections.

[Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XOQT.png)

**Finally** this what the what it looks like, I believe it is not picking up my resources folder, however I am not sure if this is the case

**Once this is done** I click Build Artifact and upload .JAR file to Amazon AWS Elastic BeanStalk
[What appears after JAR configuration is completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxjsx.png)

**However once this is done I get  a 404**

```
  HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.63
```

This is my controllers

```
   @Controller
public class HomeController {




    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() throws IOException {
       return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/search-country")
    public String login()
    {
        System.out.println("controller hit");
        return "Search";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home-page",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView homepage(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

        ApiCaller apiCaller = new ApiCaller(request.getParameter("country_text"));

        ModelAndView coronavirus = new ModelAndView("coronavirus");

        coronavirus.addObject("country_flag_url",apiCaller.getFlagURL());
        coronavirus.addObject("country_text","Cases for " + request.getParameter("country_text") + "as of " + Utils.todaysDate());
        coronavirus.addObject("total_cases_text","Cumulative Cases: " + Utils.addCommasToNumericString(apiCaller.getTotalCases()));
        coronavirus.addObject("deaths_today_text","Deaths today: " + Utils.addCommasToNumericString(apiCaller.getDeathsToday()));
        coronavirus.addObject("cases_today_text","Cases today: " + Utils.addCommasToNumericString(apiCaller.getCasesToday()));
        coronavirus.addObject("in_critical_care_text","In Intensive Care:" + Utils.addCommasToNumericString(apiCaller.getInCriticalCare()));
        coronavirus.addObject("population_text","Total Population: " +Utils.addCommasToNumericString(apiCaller.getInCriticalCare()));
        coronavirus.addObject("active_text","Active cases: " + Utils.addCommasToNumericString(apiCaller.getActiveCases()));
        coronavirus.addObject("recovered_text","Recovered Cases" + Utils.addCommasToNumericString(apiCaller.getRecovered()));
        coronavirus.addObject("deaths","Total deaths: " + Utils.addCommasToNumericString(apiCaller.getTotalCases()));




        return coronavirus;
    }

}
```